# Serverless AWS stack - need to ApiGatewayRestApi in stack with IAM roles, with no Lambdas or HTTP endpoints?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I currently have a stack deployed to AWS which has a lot of REST endpoints (Lambda functions), some other Lambdas for maintenance operations, and a DynamoDB, Cognito User Pool, Elastic Search Domain, IAM roles etc. It's all deployed with the serverless framework, using serverless.yml for defining the stack.

In order to avoid the 200 resources limit (and get a better structure), I'm trying to split the current stack into multiple stacks.

The plan is to keep the current stack for all the resources with persisted data (DynamoDB, Elastic Search, Cognito, IAM etc), and then define new stacks for the lambda functions. One for the maintenance functions, and a couple of other stacks for different types for functions invoked by HTTP through API Gateway.

Now to the problem: I have commented out the entire `functions:` section of `serverless.yml`.

I have a section containing the resources, which looks like this:

```yaml
resources:
  - ${file(resources/dynamoDb.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/cognito.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/iam.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/elasticsearch.yml)}
```

When I try do deploy the stack now (with all functions commented out), I get this error:

`Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ApiGatewayRestApi] in the Resources block of the template`

The reason that I get this error is probably because I have a reference to `ApiGatewayRestApi` in `resources/iam.yml`:

```yaml
  GetVehicleByLicensePlatePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: GetVehicleByLicensePlate
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: execute-api:Invoke
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "arn:aws:execute-api"
                  - ":"
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - ":"
                  - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                  - ":"
                  - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
                  - "/*/GET/vehicles/licenseplate/*"
```

I understand that the `ApiGatewayRestApi` reference does not resolve when I have removed all functions triggered by HTTP, since there's no API Gateway being deployed in this stack.

I'll have the HTTP lambda functions in a couple of other stacks, but these stacks will depend on this one. (And I sure don't want circular dependencies.)

So how do I make it possible for my "main" stack to have a reference to the API Gateway used by the sub-stacks?

What is the common/best practice way to solve this problem?

Comment: As a workaround, just create a dummy lambda/http proxy integration

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by moving the API gateway specific IAM roles to the stack that contains the relevant endpoints. That actually makes sense to me, since the root stack does not need to know about api endpoint specific roles.